# How do i pass a variable in the xmlhttp.send function

Tags: ajax

How do i pass a variable in the xmlhttp.send function

```
var str = "hello"
xmlhttp.open("POST","./omnama.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=+str"); ' it fills the database with str but not with hello
```

I tried these not working

```
 xmlhttp.send("fname=" +str,"lname=" +cool);
```

it fills the fname with variable value but not lname, lname gives an empty string how do i combine if i have many variables to pass on ?

Comment: xmlhttp.send("fname=" + str);

Comment: @kukipei its working post it as answer i would accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.send("fname=" + str); it should work

xmlhttp.send("fname=" +str + "&lname=" +cool);
```

Comment: I tried these way not working please help with these    xmlhttp.send("fname=" +str,"lname=" +cool);

Comment: wow its working but gosh the syntax is too hard to understand could you explain with comments please !

Comment: It is not so complicated. As Quentin said it has to be string. Maybe this is easier to understand: var somestr = "fname=" +str + "&lname=" +cool; xmlhttp.send(somestr);

Comment: I think the fundamental misunderstanding is: `xmlhttp.send` tankes no more than one argument. If you want to send two parameters, you'll have to manually construct one string representing them both. Note that the required format depends on the server-side implementation, but usually `var1=val1&var2=val2` is good.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a string. Treat it like any other string.

```
foo("some string" + another_string_stored_in_a_variable);
```